# UITabBar: setting selected index is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to deny a certain tabBarItem from pulling its action if there is no internet connection.

This is my code:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
    ONLog(@"tab selected: %@", item.title);

    if (item.tag == 2) {
        if (![[InternetManager sharedManager] isInternetWorking]) {
            [self setSelectedIndex:1];
            UIAlertView *noInternet = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Internet Connection" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [noInternet show];
        }
    }
}
```

Issue is: The alert view is being called but the "setSelectedIndex" is not doing its work...

Any ideas?

Comment: do you get inside the second condition?

Comment: of course... I said the alert view is being called :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check what the value of self.selectedItem is when the method is first called. Maybe the selected item isn't actually set as selected until after this method is called, so [self setSelectedIndex:1] is being called but the item that the user tapped gets selected immediately after.

Comment: I'm trying to check apple docs to see if anything will help you. Am I correct in assuming that this is code for a UITabBar xib? I'm looking at something like
[tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITabBarControllerDelegate/tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:), where you can simply return NO to stop the selection from occurring.

Comment: I would recommend a better solution and will continue looking for one, but a quick fix could be adding a button on top of the particular `UITabBarItem`. Then inside of the `btnPressed` function you can call `[self setSelectedIndex:2]` to do the selection programmatically if `[[InternetManager sharedManager] isInternetWorking]` is true.